# Python cx_Oracle - illegal bind variable when passing a dict with extra values

Tags: python, oracle, cx-oracle

I have gone through this 10 times now, even copied the variable out into Excel to check equality, I cannot understand why cx_Oracle is complaining about these bind variables.

```
# Build and collect the bind variables, i.e. collect all of the parameters for inserting the deltas for the deleted records into the event stream reporting table
    for row in cursor_analytics.fetchall():
        r = reg(cursor_analytics, row, False)
        logging.info("Registration status date delete record being processed for %s (%s)", r.REGISTRATION_UID, r.STATUS)
        bind_var = {
            "snapshot_id_old"       :       r.SNAPSHOT_ID_OLD,
            "snapshot_id_new"       :       r.SNAPSHOT_ID_NEW,
            "change_type"           :       change_type,
            "snapshot_date"         :       r.SNAPSHOT_DATE,
            "status_group"          :       r.STATUS_GROUP,
            "status"                :       r.STATUS,
            "status_date"           :       r.STATUS_DATE,
            "date_type"             :       r.STATUS,
            "as_of_dt"              :       r.AS_OF_DT,
            "status_remarks"        :       r.STATUS_REMARKS,
            "version_seq"           :       r.VERSION_SEQ,
            "registration_uid"      :       r.REGISTRATION_UID,
            "distribution_type"     :       r.DISTRIBUTION_TYPE,
            "country_display_label" :       r.COUNTRY_DISPLAY_LABEL,
            "flag_passive"          :       r.FLAG_PASSIVE,
            "authorization_status"  :       r.AUTHORIZATION_STATUS,
            "drug_product_id"       :       r.DRUG_PRODUCT_ID,
            "preferred_trade_name"  :       r.PREFERRED_TRADE_NAME,
            "application_stage"     :       r.APPLICATION_STAGE,
            "application_type"      :       r.APPLICATION_TYPE,
            "registration_name_details" :   r.REGISTRATION_NAME_DETAILS,
            "internal_ref_no"           :   r.INTERNAL_REF_NO,
            "registration_set_id"       :   r.REGISTRATION_SET_ID,
            "local_tradename"           :   r.LOCAL_TRADENAME,
            "reg_remarks"               :   r.REMARKS,
            "reg_comments"              :   r.COMMENTS,
            "renewal_required"          :   r.RENEWAL_REQUIRED,
            "next_renewal_date"         :   r.NEXT_RENEWAL_DATE,
            "primary_key_name"          :   "RECORD_ID",
            "primary_key_value"         :   r.RECORD_ID,
            "date_before"               :   r.STATUS_DATE,
            "date_after"                :   None

        };

        binds.append(bind_var);

        # Generate the SQL to perform the insert into the event stream table
        sql_event = """
               INSERT INTO analytics.python_event_stream (
    
                snapshot_id_old,
                snapshot_id_new,
                change_type,
                snapshot_date,
                status_group,
                status,
                status_date,
                date_type,
             
                status_remarks,
                version_seq,
                registration_uid,
                distribution_type,
                country_display_label,
                flag_passive,
                authorization_status,
                drug_product_id,
                preferred_trade_name,
                application_stage,
                application_type,
                registration_name_details,
                internal_ref_no,
                registration_set_id,
                local_tradename,
                reg_remarks,
                reg_comments,
                renewal_required,
                next_renewal_date,
                primary_key_name,
                primary_key_value,
                date_before,
                date_after
    
    
                   ) VALUES (            
                        :snapshot_id_old,
                        :snapshot_id_new,
                        :change_type,
                        :snapshot_date,
                        :status_group,
                        :status,
                        :status_date,
                        :date_type,
                        
                        :status_remarks,
                        :version_seq,
                        :registration_uid,
                        :distribution_type,
                        :country_display_label,
                        :flag_passive,
                        :authorization_status,
                        :drug_product_id,
                        :preferred_trade_name,
                        :application_stage,
                        :application_type,
                        :registration_name_details,
                        :internal_ref_no,
                        :registration_set_id,
                        :local_tradename,
                        :reg_remarks,
                        :reg_comments,
                        :renewal_required,
                        :next_renewal_date,
                        :primary_key_name,
                        :primary_key_value,
                        :date_before,
                        :date_after
                   )
    
               """

        # We are batch inserting, using the binds[] list of dicts
       
        print("about to execute with bind_var:", bind_var)
        cursor_analytics_2.execute(sql_event, bind_var)
```

But I am geting this error, regardless of whether I batch (executemany) or single execute.

```
Exception occurred
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/ariel_deltas/main.py", line 227, in <module>
    generate_event_stream(snapshot_id)
  File "C:\ariel_deltas\events.py", line 37, in generate_event_stream
    generate_reg_status_events(previous_snapshot_id, current_snapshot_id)
  File "C:\ariel_deltas\events.py", line 2433, in generate_reg_status_events
    cursor_analytics_2.execute(sql_event, bind_var)
cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number
Exception occurred
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/ariel_deltas/main.py", line 227, in <module>
    generate_event_stream(snapshot_id)
  File "C:\ariel_deltas\events.py", line 37, in generate_event_stream
    generate_reg_status_events(previous_snapshot_id, current_snapshot_id)
  File "C:\ariel_deltas\events.py", line 2433, in generate_reg_status_events
    cursor_analytics_2.execute(sql_event, bind_var)
cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number
Flagging snapshot events for release: 481  status is FAIL
Flagging snapshot events for release: 481  status is FAIL
```

Even when I boil it down to this in the final execution it fails with the same error:

```
sql_event = """
               INSERT INTO analytics.python_event_stream (    
                snapshot_id_old
                   ) VALUES (            
                        :snapshot_id_old
                   )
    
               """
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue was my dictionary of bind variables I was passing in had more values than there were bind variables in the sql.  I had thought Oracle would just ignore them as the names in the dict, didnt map to a bind variable...instead it just gives a very cryptic messages.

My dictionary had values for "AS_OF_DT" key, but this wasnt part of the the SQL.

Lesson:  Your dictionary cannot have any redundancy in it, when using a dict to populate bind variables.  Don't expect Oracle to simply discard anything in the dict which doesn't map to a bind variable, even if all the bind variables are covered by other values in the dict.